# Could not start the event log service on Local Computer

Tags: windows-event-log, windows

I'm getting a strange error on my windows 2003 R2 - Enterprise Edition w/ service pack 2 server

```
Could not start the event log service on Local Computer

Error 1075: The dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion.
```

Is there any idea as to what could be causing this or how i can remedy it?

Answer (score 1):

Event log service has no dependencies on other services by default, so this message means:
a) somebody added incorrect dependency to Event Log service
b) files of this service was corrupted or have insufficient access rights. In this case you can try to monitor system with process monitor to find out the problem or you can try to restore system files with sfc /scannow command.